# Landscape Wrong Way Around?

Tags: tables, landscape

I'm making a table in LaTeX and it's come out the wrong way! When I use landscape it is upside down. I'd like it to have the top of the page on the right side, or even better just have the text display the right way up if possible, running left to right. Can anyone advise? Here's my current code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{tabularx}{.7\textwidth}{>{\bfseries}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & J & K & L & M & N & O & P & Q & R & S & T & U & V & W & X & Y & Z\\
\hhline{----}
\hhline{~---}
\end{tabularx}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

And it spits this out: [image]

(FYI I know it's an ugly table, it's a WIP :) )

Comment: [Wellcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) And thank you for the example. Try `pdflscape` instead of `lscape`. Off-Topic: Do you now the `*{<number>}{<columndeclaration>}` syntax?

Comment: @Schweinebacke Thank you for your help. I'm using the online ShareLaTeX editor, so I'm unsure if I have access to pdflatex's tools. Could you possibly tell me how to use pdflscape as I'm struggling to find references to it on Google. And regarding the off topic, I'm afraid not as this is an example I'm reading off, which is probably the reason ABC cols look different. I've updated the image to my current solution.

Comment: Replace `\usepackage{lscape}` by `\usepackage{pdflscape}`. See [the package manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/pdflscape.pdf).

Comment: @Schweinebacke Oh, that was simple. And effective. Problem solved, thank you :)

Comment: @Schweinebacke Regarding the off topic point you mentioned earlier, if you don't mind, I'm curious why the first column isn't bordered with a line as specified in the \begin{tabularx}. Is this to do with the notation I've used? Here is how it looks now [image](http://imgur.com/a/r9vH4)